# replace some text in a mysql column

Tags: mysql, replace

given those strings in a mysql column...

```
All of the above  (-2/2)
All of the above  (0/3)
Once or twice  (1/3)
```

is it possible to do a replace in order to delete the brackets and their content?

thanks

Comment: Do you store _exactly_ those strings, or is the `(n/n)` variable?

Comment: yes, unfortunately is variable...

Comment: But otherwise, the text is either `All of the above` or `Once or twice`? And you want the end result to strip off the `(n/n)` entirely, resulting in `All of the above` or `Once or twice`?

Comment: the text is variable and the content inside the brackets is variable as well
I need to remove all brackets and content

Comment: Still not clear - I thought it was but your last comment confuses me a little. Please edit your question post a sample of existing rows, and a corresponding sample of what the expected output looks like.  MySQL does not have native regular expression replacements, unfortunately, but this may be doable with regular string operations.

Comment: I think without Regex is impossible. I'll use php or perl! .thanks for your reply!

Comment: No it isn't impossible, it can be done with `SUBSTR(), LOCATE()` and `REPLACE()`.

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
create table rep(
sometext text
);
insert into rep(sometext) values('All of the above  (-2/2)'),
('All of the above  (0/3)'),
('Once or twice  (1/3)');
update rep set sometext = replace(sometext,substring(sometext,locate('(',sometext)),'');
```

I used replace, then I found the substring of the text using locate, to send it as second arg to replace.

**References:**
[Locate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) , [substring](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) , [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

[**FIDDLE.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f276b/2)

Comment: Probably wrap that in `RTRIM()` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thins this is not exactly what I need, because if I have this row
    "All of the above (some text) bla bla (1/2)"
I should get
    "All of the above (some text) bla bla"

anyway thanks for your help

Comment: @user3174311 - which row do you mean?!

Comment: basically, I need to replace "/\s\(\d\/\d\)/" with an empty string

Comment: ok, i don't see the problem here?! the only thing you are missing is the space which as Michael mentioned you can wrap the update with RTRIM to solve it!!